# Summarizing a table by the latest date column selecting only one value from two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS access to track equipment (The equipment reference is in the first column : EquipmentID, some of the equipment can be attached to other equipment or be separate)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0a56/1/0
The table is similar to this

```
EquipmentID | AuxiliaryID | Location | LastDate | OtherInfo
_____________________________________________________________
Truck 1     | Trailer 2   | Town 1   |01/02/2016| Info 1     |
Truck 2     | Trailer 3   | Town 2   |01/03/2016| Info 2     |
Truck 3     |             | Town 3   |01/04/2016| Info 3     |
Truck 4     |             | Town 4   |01/05/2016| Info 4     |
Trailer 1   |             | Town 5   |01/06/2016| Info 5     |
Trailer 2   |             | Town 6   |01/01/2016| Info 6     |
Trailer 3   |             | Town 7   |01/08/2016| Info 7     |
```

I'm trying to work out the status of the equipment (the last location specified by the latest date). What I'm trying to achieve is the following table:

```
EquipmentID | AuxiliaryID | Location | LastDate | OtherInfo
_____________________________________________________________
Truck 1     | Trailer 2   | Town 1   |01/02/2016| Info 1
Truck 2     |             | Town 2   |01/03/2016| Info 2
Truck 3     |             | Town 3   |01/04/2016| Info 3
Truck 4     |             | Town 4   |01/05/2016| Info 4
Trailer 1   |             | Town 5   |01/06/2016| Info 5
Trailer 3   |             | Town 7   |01/08/2016| Info 7
```

- If a value from EquimentID is not present in AuxiliaryID, return that row for example : Truck 3, Truck 4, Trailer 3 . Return that row
- If a value from EquipmentID is present in AuxliaryID (Trailer 2, Trailer 3), compare the dates (LastDate) in order to check for the latest.

  - Trailer 2 is present in the first row and sixth row, but the first row have got the latest date, so do not return the sixth row
  - Trailer 3 is present in the second row and last row, but the last row is the latest datee, so return the last row and remove the auxiliaryID from the first row

Would I be able to do that in an SQL Query?

Comment: please add more description about your desired output.

Comment: You want the same output as the original table, unless one of these conditions is true:

1. A piece of equipment has been in the AuxiliaryID column later than it has been in the EquipmentID column, or

2. A piece of equipment has been in the EquipmentID column later than it has been in the AuxiliaryID column.

In case 1, you want the record returned where the equipment is in the AuxiliaryID column.

In case 2, you want the record returned where equipment is in the EquipmentID column, and you don't want it displayed anywhere in the AuxiliaryID column.

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing my request a-cat-named-midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try.

```
SELECT
t1.EquipmentID, 
t2.EquipmentID as AuxiliaryID, 
t1.Location, 
t1.LastDate, 
t1.OtherInfo
FROM Trucks t1
left join Trucks t2 on t1.AuxiliaryID = t2.EquipmentID and t1.LastDate > t2.LastDate
inner join (
  select EquipmentID, max(LastDate) as MaxLastDate
  from (
    select EquipmentID, LastDate
    from Trucks
    UNION
    select AuxiliaryID, LastDate
    from Trucks where AuxiliaryID is not null) a
    group by EquipmentID) maxdates 
  on t1.EquipmentID = maxdates.EquipmentID and t1.LastDate = maxdates.MaxLastDate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last row by finding the maximum date and choosing the row with that information.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from Trucks as t
where t.LastDate = (select max(t2.LastDate)
                    from Trucks as t2
                    where t2.EquipmentId = t.EquipmentId
                   );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I would like the values in the result to be unique in EquipmentID and AuxiliaryID

Comment: @AminTN . . . That is not true of your sample data.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question.  It is rude to change the question in a way that invalidates answers.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding Gordon. The problem needs a better description, I have put the input table and expected output. Your query returns the same table as the input.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
select
  max(case when src = 'e' then p.equipmentID end) as equipID,
  max(case when src = 'a' then p.EquipmentID end) as auxID,
  Location,
  t.LastDate,
  OtherInfo
from
  trucks t inner join
  (select
    src,
    EquipmentID,
    LastDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EquipmentID ORDER BY lastDate desc) rn
   from
    (SELECT 'e' as src, EquipmentID, LastDate FROM Trucks
     union all
     SELECT 'a' as src, AuxiliaryID, LastDate FROM Trucks 
            where AuxiliaryID is not null) u) p on
   rn = 1 and
   t.lastdate = p.LastDate and
   (t.equipmentid = p.equipmentid  or
    t.auxiliaryID = p.equipmentid ) 
group by Location, t.LastDate, OtherInfo
order by t.LastDate
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0a56/77)

Comment: Thank you for the anser Beth, I have chosen the other answer because ROW_NuMBER is in supported in access